# How to Roll up duplicate IDs in a column into one row and display the results

Tags: r, google-analytics

I have clickstream data from Google Analytics in R with the following

```
columns: 
UserID, SessionID, TimeStamp, PagePath, PageViews
```

The UserIDs are duplicated throughout the data set like so because a UserID would have multiple pagepaths, timestamps, and even SessionIDs.

```
UserID Column    SessionID    TimeStamp   PagePath             PageViews
1                  1.1          12:01      google.com             1
1                  1.1          12:03      google.com/products    1
1                  1.1          12:06      google.com/info        1
1                  1.1          12:08      google.com/purchase    1 
2                  2.1          09:07      google.com             1
2                  2.1          09:13      google.com/info        1
```

What I want to do is be able to do is find a package or some type of way 
to put this in a dataframe where I can use with Clickstream Package in R 
so the results would look like so :

```
UserID        PagePathBrokenOut
1             google.com,products,info
2             google.com,info
```

What function or package in R would accomplish this. I can't use `c(` 
because there are literally thousands upon thousands of userIDs and 
paths

I have explored the `data.frame` function and `dplyr` but haven't had much 
luck ... there has to be a way to condense `UserID` to a singular row and 
then display out the pagepaths.

I have tried `dplyr` and `data.frame` as well as `reshape` but again none of 
those have worked so far

Again if there is a way to consolidate multiple user ids in one singular 
column into 1 row with the respective paths that would be awesome.

I have tried to use `dplyr` but it hasn't worked

```
path <- ddply(mydata, "userID",function(df1)paste(df1$pagepath,collapse = ","))
```

Comment: Notes: `ddply` is from `plyr`, not `dplyr`. Your suggested output is more than just group/summarize, since you're changing the `PathPath`. Have you gotten far enough to be able to break them out? What should happen if one `UserID` has multiple websites (not just `google.com`)?

Comment: BTW: please show your effort so far. Also, be aware that this might receive VTC (votes to close) since you are literally asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library"* which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (while I confess there is not a great alternative, just https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

## `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(Page = gsub("/.*", "", PagePath),
         Path = trimws(gsub("^/|?$", "", gsub("^[^/]*", "", PagePath)))) %>%
  group_by(UserID, Page) %>%
  summarize(PagePathBrokenOut = paste(c(Page[1], Filter(nzchar, Path)), collapse = ",")) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   UserID Page       PagePathBrokenOut                
#    <int> <chr>      <chr>                            
# 1      1 google.com google.com,products,info,purchase
# 2      2 google.com google.com,info
```

## `data.table`

(Note: I'm using the `magrittr` package only to break out the pipe-line of calls, not that it is required to do this. It is not.)

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
datDT %>%
  .[, c("Page", "Path") := .(gsub("/.*", "", PagePath),
                             trimws(gsub("^/|?$", "", gsub("^[^/]*", "", PagePath)))), ] %>%
  .[, .(PagePathBrokenOut = paste(c(Page[1], Filter(nzchar, Path)), collapse = ",")),
    by = c("UserID", "Page")]
#    UserID       Page                 PagePathBrokenOut
# 1:      1 google.com google.com,products,info,purchase
# 2:      2 google.com                   google.com,info
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
UserID    SessionID    TimeStamp   PagePath             PageViews
1           1.1          12:01      google.com             1
1           1.1          12:03      google.com/products    1
1           1.1          12:06      google.com/info        1
1           1.1          12:08      google.com/purchase    1 
2           2.1          09:07      google.com             1
2           2.1          09:13      google.com/info        1 ")
```

Comment: Thank You ! I used this approach and altered it a bit but it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that could be useful for some cases:

```
#Remove non required columns and spread
df2 <- df %>%
  select(UserID, PagePath, PageViews) %>%
  spread(PagePath, PageViews)

#Temporal vector to store UserIDs and remove it from df2
UserIDTemp <- df2$UserID
df2$UserID <- NULL

#Populate data frame with URLs instead of page views. NAs will be generated
w <- which(!is.na(df2), arr.ind = TRUE)
df2[w] <- names(df2)[w[, "col"]]

#Paste/concatenate all paths into a single string
df_args <- c(df2, sep = ", ")
pastedPaths <-  do.call(paste, df_args)

#Create data frame with UserIDs and paths
PagePaths <- data.frame(UserIDTemp, pastedPaths)

data.frame(UserIDTemp,pastedPaths)
# UserIDTemp                                                  pastedPaths
# 1 google.com, google.com/info, google.com/products, google.com/purchase
# 2                                   google.com, google.com/info, NA, NA
```

Data:

```
#Replicate data frame
UserID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
SessionID <- c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.1, 2.1)
TimeStamp <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
PagePath <-
  c(
    "google.com",
    "google.com/products",
    "google.com/info",
    "google.com/purchase",
    "google.com",
    "google.com/info"
  )
PageViews <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(UserID, SessionID, TimeStamp, PagePath, PageViews)
```

Comment: Thank You so Much! I was able to piece together what you sent and researched Ddply more and was able to complete this!!!